# How do I prevent an infinite call stack from occurring when generating a large binary grid?

Tags: javascript, recursion, matrix, while-loop, callstack

I'm working on a web-app implementation of Binary Sudoku that recursively generates random, solved boards, after which it reduces the amount of tiles on the grid down to a valid starting point for players to solve the board. This strategy works great with my 4x4 and 6x6 boards, currently.

** Not necessary to know for this problem, but if you are confused about how the game works:

** Players must solve the board by adhering to three rules of logic:

** Each row and column must contain an equal amount of red tiles (0's) and blue tiles (1's)

** Each row and column must be unique

** More than two of the same colored tiles placed consecutively in a row or column are not allowed (e.g 000 or 111)

I had done some optimization to my 6x6 board generator to reduce the load on the call stack, bringing the total amount of calls down from ~1-300,000 to under 60,000 in most instances. I am now trying to build an 8x8 grid, but unfortunately, the amount of calls getting added to the call stack seems to be well over 500,000, sometimes in the million range, in the circumstances that I can get a board to even generate without exceeding the call stack limit.

I have a somewhat vague idea of how to solve this. Currently, I have a 'tracking' object in my main board class which is set up to log the total number of recursive steps each generator function is taking, by incrementing the associated tracker (key-val pair) each time a function runs. I am calling the main generating function which sets off this recursive chain in my class constructor. I am thinking that one approach might be to set an if conditional in my first function (which runs the most times), which would tell the function to return 'undefined' if it has ran more than, say, 900,000 times. And then I could set up a while loop in my class constructor that says to run my main generator as long as the first function has not ran more than 900,000 times. The problem is, I don't know what to do in the case that my function has ran 900,000 times and returns undefined. I obviously want to keep running it until I generate a board within my call stack limit, but I don't know how to achieve that.

This is how I have my generating functions set up currently, I tried my best to omit as much of the redundant code as possible and replace with pseudo-code.

```
export default class Board8x8 {
constructor() {
    this.currentGrid = [];
    this.stats = {
        Function1: 0,
        Function2: 0,
        Function3: 0,
        Function4: 0
    };

    // while (this.stats.Function1 < 900000) { ?? Vague idea of how to implement
        this.assembledBoard = this.checkColumnsUnique(); // Last function, starts chain
    // }
    
};

assembleRows(row = []) {
    // First function, runs the most times
    // if (this.stats.Function1 > 900000) return undefined; ??
    this.stats.Function1++;

    const permutations = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0]];
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        //Grab 4 random permutations and throw them together as a row
        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * permutations.length);

        row.push(...permutations[randomIndex]);
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        // Check for triplet values within row, if found, recurse
    };

    let total = 0;
    row.forEach(val => total += val);
    // Checks to see if there are even amount of 0's and 1's in each row, returns if so
    if (total === 4) return row;
    
    return this.assembleRows();
};

assembleGrid(visited = new Set(), grid = []) {
    this.stats.Function2++;
    while (grid.length < 8) {
        const randomRow = this.assembleRows();
        if (!visited.has(randomRow.join(''))) {
            // Check rows for duplicates
            visited.add(randomRow.join(''))
            grid.push(randomRow);
        };
    };

    const cols = { c0: [], ... c7: [] };
    for (let row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
        for (let col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
            // Push all column values into corresponding column array
    };

    const colValues = Object.values(cols);
    for (let row = 0; row < colValues.length; row++) {
        for (let col = 0; col < colValues[row].length; col++) {
            // Check for triplet values within column, if found, recurse
        };
    };

    return grid;
};

checkColumnTotals() {
    this.stats.Function3++;
    const values = { c0: 0, ... c7: 0 };

    const grid = this.assembleGrid();
    for (let row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
        for (let col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
            // Add up all column values in each column
        };
    };

    let check = 0;
    Object.values(values).forEach(val => {if (Number(val) === 4) check++});
    // If column has even amount of 0's and 1's, increment check

    if (check === 8) return grid;
    // If every column is even, return grid, otherwise, recurse

    return this.checkColumnTotals();
};

checkColumnsUnique(visited = new Set()) {
    this.stats.Function4++;
    const cols = { c0: [] ... c7: [] };

    const grid = this.checkColumnTotals();
    for (let row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
        // Push all column values into corresponding array
        };
    };

    const colValues = Object.values(cols);
    for (let col = 0; col < colValues.length; col++) {
        // If any columns are duplicate, recurse
    };

    this.currentGrid = grid;
    // Finally, return the grid if all constraints are met and allow reduction to occur
    return grid;
};
```

Any insights into this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The rules seem very simple, but I'm not sure why you even need recursion in the first place.   Rules 1 & 2 can be bounded while generating random 0/1's, could be short circuited if a rule can't be found, and the last rule if not met, just re-run.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why recursion is required, so I've knocked up a simple snippet that seems to fit all the rules, I've commented the code to try and explain how I done it.

It's basically a brute force approach..

Just click the "Make Board" button to get a fresh new board.

```js
function rand01() {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) return 1
  else return 0;
}

function tryMakeBoard(size) {
  if (size < 2 || !Number.isInteger(size/2)) {
    //make sure board is divisable by 2,
    //as there has to be the same amount 
    //of 0's, as 1's.
    throw new Error('Invalid board size');
  } 
  //create 2 dim array 
  const ret = new Array(size);
  //have to have the same amount of 0's & 1's.
  //so the max of each is size div 2
  const evenCount = size / 2;
  
  for (let y = 0; y < size; y ++) {
    ret[y] = [];
    for (let x = 0; x < size; x ++) {
      let iRand = rand01();
      let ok = false;
      //can only put a 0 or 1 here, 
      //so loop 2 and flip for second loop
      for (let trys = 0; trys < 2; trys ++) {
        //ok lets just pick a random number
        ret[y][x] = iRand;
        //lets make sure we don't have the same numbers
        //more than 2 in the X
        ok = x < 2 || (!(
            ret[y][x] === ret[y][x-1] && 
            ret[y][x] === ret[y][x-2]));
        if (!ok) { 
          iRand = Number(!iRand); //flip 0/1
          continue; 
        }
        //now for the y
        ok = y < 2 || (!(
            ret[y][x] === ret[y-1][x] && 
            ret[y][x] === ret[y-2][x]));
        if (!ok) { 
          iRand = Number(!iRand); //flip 0/1
          continue; 
        }
        //lets make sure we don't have either X counts > evenCount
        //it's binary so basically the sum is not more than evenCount
        if (x === size -1) {
          let sum = 0;
          for (let l = 0; l <= x; l ++) {
            if (ret[y][l]) sum ++;
          }
          if (sum !== evenCount) return false;
        }
        //now do the same for y
        if (y === size -1) {
          let sum = 0;
          for (let l = 0; l <= y; l ++) {
            if (ret[l][x]) sum ++;
          }
          if (sum !== evenCount) return false;
        }
        //so far so good
        break; 
      }
     
      if (!ok) {
        //we can't make sure that doubles can't happen
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  //finally lets make sure all row columns are unique.
  var s = new Set();
  //first rows
  for (let l = 0; l < size; l ++) {
    s.add(ret[l].join(''));
  }
  if (s.size !== size) return false;
  //and cols
  s.clear();
  for (let l = 0; l < size; l ++) {
    s.add(ret.map(m => m[l]).join(''))
  }
  if (s.size !== size) return false;  
  return ret;
}

function makeBoard(size) {
  //lets try a few times,..
  for (let l = 0; l < 10000000; l ++) { 
    const r = tryMakeBoard(size);  
    if (r) return r;
  }
  return false;
}

const boardEl = document.querySelector('#board');
const btnEl = document.querySelector('button');

function makeNewBoard() {
  const board = makeBoard(8);
  let txt = '';
  boardEl.innerHTML = '';
  for (let l = 0; l < board.length; l ++) {
    const row = document.createElement('div');
    for (let x = 0; x < board[l].length; x ++) {
      const sp = document.createElement('span');
      sp.innerText = board[l][x];
      if (board[l][x]) {
        sp.classList.add('one');
      } else sp.classList.add('zero');
      row.appendChild(sp);
    }
    boardEl.appendChild(row);
  }
}

btnEl.addEventListener('click', makeNewBoard);

makeNewBoard();
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 1.1em;
  height: 1.1em;
  border: 1px solid white;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.one {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.zero {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

#board {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<button>Make Board</button>

<div>
  <div id="board">
  </div>
<div>
```